# regex get string after two keywords (from and to)

Tags: regex

I have string

```
changed the applicant's name from Brian David Vaughn to Brian Hamish Vaughn
```

I will take names of the string after keywords 'from' and 'to' words using regex. I have tried to use this pattern to get string after 'from':

```
(?<=from)\s+\S+\s\S+(?:\s\S+){0,1}
```

But, it doesn't work to get from two keyword, like this pattern:

```
(?<=from|to)\s+\S+\s\S+(?:\s\S+){0,1}
```

How is the correct pattern?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 'Brian David Vaughn' and 'Brian Hamish Vaughn'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import re
s = "changed the applicant's name from Brian David Vaughn to Brian Hamish Vaughn"
matches = re.findall("(?:from|to)\W(.+?)(?=\W[a-z]|$)", s)
```

gives

```
['Brian David Vaughn', 'Brian Hamish Vaughn']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be very straightforward since you have keywords

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "changed the applicant's name from Brian David Vaughn to Brian Hamish Vaughn"
>>> re.findall('(?=.*) from (.*) to (.*)',s1)
[('Brian David Vaughn', 'Brian Hamish Vaughn')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the number of word occurrences to be matched, another option is to match at least a single non whitespace char using `\S` followed by matching as least as possible chars until the next encounter of `from` or `to` or the end of the string `$`

```
\b(?:from|to)\s+(\S.*?)(?=\s+(?:from|to)\b|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b(?:from|to)\s+` Match either from or to and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match a single non whitespace char followed by as least as possible chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `\s+(?:from|to)\b` Match either 1+ whitespace chars followed by `from` or `to`
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6U7Iv3/1)